# APN (Apple Push Notification) payload size limit

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) you can find the info:

> Each push notification includes a payload. The payload contains
>   information about how the system should alert the user as well as any
>   custom data you provide. The maximum size allowed for a notification
>   payload is **256 bytes**; Apple Push Notification Service refuses any
>   notification that exceeds this limit.

However in WWDC 14 we can see this screenshot:

[image]

I wonder if there is any official Apple statement about the size limit of push notification. I tested it and larger that 256 bytes works, but documentation said it shouldn't. Can someone confirm or deny the size of remote notifications?

Comment: From my own testing, it fits about 3-4 lines of text that you see on the alert popup screen. Each line has about a few words. I tend to think it resembles the amount you can write inside a Tweet, maybe a little bit lesser. I don't know about refusing the notification but I do know that if I put more text than 3 - 4 lines, they get truncated and not shown.

Comment: It looks like Apple haven't updated their APNS docs yet. I couldn't find any official Apple doc that mentions the increase in payload size.

Comment: 256 bytes for iOS7- and 2KB for iOS8+. Fore HTTP/2 its 4KB. Read more : http://www.jeenalinfotech.com/blogs/ios/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-apple-push-notification/

Comment: @Zhang notifications can also be used to send *data* that is *not shown to the user*; hence the interest in knowing how large the payload can be.

Comment: I'm using VOIP and alert object size still truncate nearly around ~1KB. How max limit 5KB can be used in case of VOIP. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Apple has already updated the documentation. The 2KB for the maximum payload size is just for devices running iOS 8. The [official doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html) says:

> In iOS 8 and later, the maximum size allowed for a notification
>   payload is 2 kilobytes; Apple Push Notification service refuses any
>   notification that exceeds this limit. (Prior to iOS 8 and in OS X, the
>   maximum payload size is 256 bytes.)

---

**As per the updated [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html) the size is 4KB.**

- For regular remote notifications, the maximum size is 4KB (4096 bytes)
- For Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP) notifications, the maximum size is 5KB (5120 bytes)
  NOTE

> If you are using the legacy APNs binary interface to send
>   notifications instead of an HTTP/2 request, the maximum payload size
>   is 2KB (2048 bytes)

Comment: I want to mention that in contrast to the docs the 256 byte limit does not seem to apply to iOS 7. People tested and confirmed that their iOS 7 devices happily receive messages > 256 bytes. https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs/pull/79#issuecomment-51021572

Comment: So Is it 2000 bytes or 2048 bytes ?

Comment: @user1227928 clearly says 2 kilo**bytes**, so your answer is 2000 bytes. A **kibibit** `KiB` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibit) is 1024 bytes. But anyway, we all know Apple messes with these definitions (they probably use kilobytes as 1024 in software terms, but on device storage size they use 1000).

Comment: Updated documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1

Comment: @user1227928 The correct answer is 2048 bytes, not 2000 bytes, per the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html).

Comment: This explanation is now a bit dated; the documentation has [moved](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html) and the new answer is either 2048 bytes via the binary interface or 4096 bytes via the HTTP/2 API.

Comment: 2KB means 2048 bytes

Comment: @Ganesh - Actually, the point that was originally made by Alejandro, is that, by international standard (see his wiki link), `2KiB` means 2048 bytes, and `2KB` means 2000 bytes. However, in practice, `KB` has been used so commonly, for so long in computer software, to mean 1024, that it is not safe to assume either way. I myself don't abide by that standard, hard to break a habit of many decades, so I can't complain  ;)

Answer (score 32):

For iOS 9 there are some changes:

Introduction of HTTP/2

**Payload increased to 4KB**

4 KB limit apply to all versions of iOS and OS 10

Check this [official link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1)

> - For regular remote notifications, the maximum size is **4KB** (4096
>     bytes)
> - For Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP) notifications, the maximum
>     size is **5KB** (5120 bytes)
> - If you are using the legacy APNs binary interface to send notifications instead of an HTTP/2 request, the maximum payload size is **2KB** (2048 bytes)

Check this video link for more details regarding the features of HTTP/2
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-720/

Comment: this is not true yet, they will add those things in 2016, as far as I know, there is no date

Comment: http/2 apns is officially supported. https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172015b

Comment: Hi, I'm using VOIP but it still truncate alter object size to 512 byte only. How that make sense when Apple Document say it's increase to 5KB for VOIP. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3):

According to the testing from the node-apn project the size was expanded from 256 to 2KB over the beta period, I think it's likely Apple hasn't updated their documentation to reflect this change. [The discussion on the node-apn project](https://github.com/argon/node-apn/issues/181).

Edit: [Urban Airship also updated their backend for 2KB as well](http://docs.urbanairship.com/dashboard/july-2014-release.html).

Answer (score 2):

- For **regular remote notifications**, the maximum size is **4KB (4096 bytes)**
- For **Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)** notifications, the maximum size is **5KB (5120 bytes)**

**NOTE**

If you are using the legacy APNs binary interface to send notifications instead of an HTTP/2 request, the maximum payload size is 2KB (2048 bytes)

Apple Docs :
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1

Answer (score 1):

Per the most recent [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html), the payload limit is 4096 bytes or 2048 bytes for regular notifications, and 5120 bytes for VoIP notifications:

> The maximum size of the payload depends on the notification you are sending:
>
> - For regular remote notifications, the maximum size is 4KB (4096 bytes)
> - For Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP) notifications, the maximum size is 5KB (5120 bytes)
>
> Note: If you are using the legacy APNs binary interface to send notifications instead of an HTTP/2 request, the maximum payload size is 2KB (2048 bytes).

Prior to iOS 8, the limit was 256 bytes.

Comment: Good information but FYI the link is not available.

Comment: @ipr Thanks, Apple has a regular habit of moving their documentation.  Updated and included new most recent information.