# Applepushnotifications in IOS9

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Hi In IOS9 maximum   how many bytes we can sent to APNS  server, and also is it possible to send the image to APNS server

Comment: Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233730/apn-apple-push-notification-payload-size-limit)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33440803/767329 & if you will handle the BLOB object  conversion probably yes.

Answer (score 2):

[APNs Provided API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/APNsProviderAPI.html)

> The body data must not be compressed and its maximum size is 4KB (4096
>   bytes)

You can send image url (use url shortner) Then send image url via APNs

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not send image in Remote notification payload to APNS. You can send a URL for the image and then fetch the image on the device.

The maximum payload size is 4096 bytes.

You can refer [Apple's Local and Remote programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html) for the same.