# APNS Invalid Payload Size, still succeeds

Tags: ios, laravel, apple-push-notifications

I recently encountered receiving a response from APNS that a payload being sent was too large([receiving status code 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/BinaryProviderAPI.html)). What is incredibly confusing is that those push notifications are still making their way to devices. Is there anything I am overlooking that could cause a push notification to receive this status code but actually still make it to the device?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33440803/4549304 can this help?

Comment: @SaurabhYadav I am aware of the limits, I am just concerned that APNs told me that the payload was too large but that it still went through.

Comment: This should not happen using production environment. Are you using Http/2 interface or the legacy binary interface? Also, are you testing using development environment?

Answer (score 0):

error Missing payload And APNS Invalid Payload Size,etc these type error occur
when device token is invalid then these type error come so use valid device id or token