# APNS Payload Size issue

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, voip, http2

I'm writing an VOIP based iOS application. As per [official doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html), we can send data upto 5KB using VOIP, but in my case it getting failed in less then 1KB data.

I'm using **"body"** under **"alert"** attribute tag to send Big content.
Alert attribute size get truncate if text size exceeded.

In document read I also got dependency to use HTTP/2 Protocol, How this is dependent while APNS server do use XMPP protocol to send message ?

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Did you try to zip your payload?

Comment: @ridvankucuk that's interesting, how can do that :O Apart my basic question why it's not able to send data upto 5KB ? Do you think it is dependent to http/2 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233730/apn-apple-push-notification-payload-size-limit

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html

Comment: Do you think it's because Server not implemented with HTTP/2 protocol ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to get 5KB data and it is getting failed with 1KB.

Try scheduling local notification as per pushkit payload you receive and keep data in local notification's user info, that way you can keep your data within app.

Once sound file of local notification plays ( Max 30 seconds ) App will get invoke in background then you can save data in `NSUserDefault` or `SQLite` or use it for some purpose.

[Pushkit reference](https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification)

Comment: Hasya, I'm receiving VOIP push but it's truncated. I'm sending big-data in **body** attribute as added in question. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Option (1) 1 more trick you can do, once you get silent push notification and sound will play for max 30 seconds, in that time, request API on server and get data of 5KB. but this cycle has to be finish in 30 seconds. Option (2) You can also try with Base64 encoded string in push kit payload. Option (3) Get partial data in sending partial pushkit notification and combine it once you have whole part.

Comment: Thanks for tricks, but do you know issue with 5KB that apple promising for VOIP ?